# How to hide the .aspx page when jquery popup box is opened?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have an Navigation link, when user click the link, popup dialogue box is opened,at the same time i want to hide the aspx page. It means user unable to perform any operation until user click the close button in dialogue box.

Answer (score 0):

You need the modal dialog.

```
$(".selector").dialog({
  modal: true
});
```